# Who is the liar among A,B,C?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Of three persons A, B and C, one always lies while the other two always speak the truth.

- C asked A: "Do you always speak the truth, yes or no?"
- A said something that C could not understand.
- So C asked B: "What did A just say?"
- B replied: "A said NO."

So, who is the liar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> B is the liar.

The reason:

> If A is a truth-teller, he has correctly answered YES (I am a truth-teller).
>  If A is a liar, he also has answered YES (lying, as he is a liar).
>
>  So A must have said YES, and B must be lying when he claims that A said NO.